# Does source-maps in style tags work?

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, source-maps

I'm having problems with CSS within a  tag and source-maps.

In order to improve the load time of my project, I have changed the way I put the CSS in my HTML, turning this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Source-maps working wonderfully</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Into this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
        h1 { color: red };

        //more css

        /*# sourceMappingURL=css/style.css.map */
      </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Source-maps not working :(</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, during the building process, the original CSS file generated with sassc (with sourcemaps flag) is dumped into the html that will be served.

I am having troubles because it does not recognise the source-maps when the CSS is inside a  tag but it does it perfectly when i use the tag . Am I missing an extra annotation or it is not supported?

I'm using chrome.

Comment: There is a bug about this in Chromium about source maps in inline style tags, but based on this link, it should be fixed a long time ago: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456062

Not sure if Google Chrome is using the fixed Chromium core or not ...

Comment: Source maps should work from the style tags however I suggest that you combine all your CSS files into a single CSS and load that the first way - this may slow down the first page but all the rest of the website pages will load faster.

Comment: This might be an ugly hack, but you could also generate the embedded source map and then drop it inline in the tag... again, pretty ugly but if you're using a templating language for HTML it could be manageable.

Comment: In Chrome it currently kinda works/kinda fails, no matter if the sourcemap itself is external or embedded as a data uri. In my case it shows me a source, but the wrong position in a wrong file, as if it uses the wrong line for evaluating the source. 
Btw. the same approach for script tags work in Chrome, but fails in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

`/*@ sourceMappingURL=` is the old syntax, `/*# sourceMappingURL=` should be used instead.

The new Syntax is implemented in all major browser [source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/06/sourceMappingURL-and-sourceURL-syntax-changed#implementation-in-browser-devtools--done) and Internet explorer 11+ [source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2014/04/02/announcing-an-updated-version-of-internet-explorer-11-available-on-windows-8-1-windows-7-and-windows-phone-8-1/).

**Chrome dev tools**

1. Open Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Open Settings <kbd>F1</kbd>.
3. Click "Enable CSS source maps" checkbox

**Firefox dev tools**

1. Open Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Open Toolbar Options (Cog on right).
3. Click "Show original sources" checkbox

**Internet Explorer dev tools**

1. Open Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Open Debugger panel <kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd>
3. click the last icon on the right

**Safari dev tools & Firebug**

- enabled by default.

Comment: The OP used the new syntax, so this is not really an answer to his problem. But how they can be enabled, may be useful for others.